# Function in Angular controller not returning data to the $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, view, controller

Please correct me if I'm wrong:
I want to get different types of bills for different tables in my view and this is the way I thought would be the best. Which is probably not.

In my view, I call:

Table 1:

`{{billsTypeVariableIncome}}`

Table 2:

`{{billsTypeVariableBills}}`

This is how my controller looks like:

```
$scope.billsTypeVariableIncome = getBillsByType(1);
$scope.billsTypeVariableBills = getBillsByType(2);
function getBillsByType(bill_type){

        $http.get("/api/bills/by/type/"+bill_type).
        success(function(data){
           return data;

        }).
        error(function(data){

            console.log('Error ' + data);

        })
    }
```

Im a rookie(obviously) so probably my approach is wrong. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You're calling a function before it's been defined. Define `getBillsByType` before calling it, JavaScript is executed from top to bottom. 

Also, `getBillsByType` doesn't return anything. You should set the `$scope` variables inside the success callback of the `$http` promise.

Comment: Putting the function before the $scope variables didnt help neither. Tried it before. I'm pretty sure my approach is wrong. It's feels primitive to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you use an `$http` service it always returns promise since AJAX requests are asynchronous and you are not sure about when the request will be completed. So promises are used to register callbacks.

And you are expecting return data from an promise object which can't be possible. So change your code to something like this:

```
$scope.getBillsByType = function(billType, variableName) {
    $http.get("/api/bills/by/type/" + billType).
    success(function(data) {
       $scope[variableName] = data;
    }).
    error(function(data){
        console.log('Error ' + data);
    })
};

$scope.getBillsByType(1, 'billsTypeVariableIncome');
$scope.getBillsByType(2, 'billsTypeVariableBills');
```

This is just an simple example, you can do in other ways also.

Hope this helps!

Thanks,
SA

Comment: @DennisLaymi you should accept the answer, if you are not searching for one more answer.